# Service Fabric Reliable Collection Capacity

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

In some Service fabric application samples Ref:  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-iot, It check for the number items currently present in the collection , something like

```
if(currentNumberOfBufferedWorkItems >= m_MaxNumOfBufferedWorkItems)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Work Manger is at maximum buffered work items:{currentNumberOfBufferedWorkItems}");
        }
```

The current value for m_MaxNumOfBufferedWorkItems is 10000

What are the factors needed to be considered for setting the Maximum Buffer value for the Reliable collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the provided example, they use a queue to buffer items to be processed later. They check the item count to limit the size of the buffer. This is by choice, not limited by the collection itself. The size of the reliable collection is limited only by disk space on the nodes.

The buffer limit in this example should be determined by the processing capacity. If the buffer grows out of control you'd need to add more processing power.

Comment: Not sure if the size of the collections is limited only by disk space. Previously it was stated that SF reliable collections have the same restrictions as any other collection in .net — 2GB, and also it was stated that in future releases SF team will get rid of this restriction. Do I misunderstand something and there is really no restriction?

Comment: Matthew Snider (MSFT) noted that the limitation was removed some time ago in the comments here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections/ {The 2GB limit was removed some time ago (silly int). Today you are limited to memory for the size of all of your keys and disk for values (since we page out the values in the dictionary).}